# Frequency bar graph in descending order

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created a frequency graph using ggplot2. I would like the bars to go in descending order based on frequency counts. So language measures from left to right, BNT, WAB_R, BDAE...etc. Of note, my dataframe is organized with the language measures are columns and the cases are rows. The values are 0 or 1 and 1 means that the participant endorsed the language measure. I have tried using reorder in various combinations but had no luck. I appreciate the help!

Here is sample data:

```
        WAB-R     BDAE      BNT         CAT    
1          0       0         1           0
2          1       0         1           1
3          0       0         0           0
4          1       1         0           0 
5          0       0         0           1
6          0       1         1           0
7          1       0         0           0
8          0       1         1           0
```

Portion of the Data Show in New WindowClear
OutputExpand/Collapse Output

```
structure(list(WAB_R = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), WAB_B = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), BDAE = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), CAT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), BNT = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), PNT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), PyramidPalms = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), QAB = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), PALPA = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), BASA = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Compiled_lang = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -85L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Code:

```
 library(tidyverse) survey %>% select(c(WAB_R:other_lang_measure)) %>% pivot_longer(everything()) %>% filter(value==1) %>% ggplot(aes(x= value))+ geom_histogram(stat = 'count',aes(fill=name), position = position_dodge2(0.9,preserve = 'single'))+ labs(fill='Language Measures') + theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.ticks.x=element_blank()) + scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,50,5))+ ylab("Frequency Counts") + coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 45))+ ggtitle("\nLanguage Measures\n ")+ cleanup
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help (code blocks please)

Comment: And without testing your data or code, almost every question on SO that involves "ggplot2" and "order of ..." is answered by using `factor(..., levels=...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by sage **@r2evans** you would need to format as factor the x-axis variable. Also, you can compute the counts directly using `summarise()` and then arrange in order to sketch the plot:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
survey %>%
  select(c(WAB_R:Compiled_lang)) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% filter(value==1) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(value=sum(value)) %>%
  arrange(desc(value)) %>%
  mutate(name=factor(name,levels = unique(name),ordered = T)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= name,y=value))+ 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',aes(fill=name),
                 position = position_dodge2(0.9,preserve = 'single'))+
  labs(fill='Language Measures') +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.ticks.x=element_blank()) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,50,5))+
  ylab("Frequency Counts") + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 45))+ ggtitle("\nLanguage Measures\n ")
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way:

```r
survey <- structure(list(WAB_R = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                     WAB_B = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                     BDAE = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), 
                     CAT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0),
                     BNT = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), 
                     PNT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                     PyramidPalms = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                     QAB = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                     PALPA = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), 
                     BASA = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                     Compiled_lang = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), 
                row.names = c(NA, -85L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

library(tidyverse,warn.conflicts = F) 

survey %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  filter(value==1) %>% 
  count(name) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x= name, y = n)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  labs(y = "Frequency Counts", title = "Language Measures", x = "")
```

[image]

```r
survey %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  filter(value==1) %>% 
  count(name) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x= name, y = n)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  labs(y = "Frequency Counts", title = "Language Measures", x = "") + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>